# Repeatitive Items on Level 2

Tags: php, duplicates, organizational-chart

I have a page that displays an organizational tree however in level 2 there are repeated items. What I wanted to is to avoid the duplicates...

Here's the example display:

```
<ul id="org" style="display: none;">
<li>Brit School                        
    <ul>
        <li>Amy Winehouse
            <ul>
                <li>Carina Round</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Adele Adkins
            <ul>
                <li>Kreayshawn K</li>
                <li>Leona Lewis</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Adele Adkins
            <ul>
                <li>Kreayshawn K</li>
                <li>Leona Lewis</li>
            </ul>
        <li>Arctic Monkey
            <ul>
                <li>PJ Harvey</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</li>
```

I wanted to omit the 2nd record Adele this is my example code in PHP

```
<ul id="org" style="display: none;">
<?php foreach ($lvl1 as $genesA) {?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $genesA->LevelFullName1?>
        <?php if($genesA->lvlMemF) {?>
        <ul>
        <?php if($genesA->lvlMemF) {?>
            <?php foreach ($lvl2 as $genesB) {?>
                <?php if($genesB->lvlMemS) {?>
                <li><?php echo $genesB->LevelFullName2 ?>
                <?php if($genesB->lvlMemS) {?>
                  <ul>
                    <?php if($genesB->lvlMemS) {?>
                        <?php foreach ($lvl3 as $genesC) {?>
                            <?php if($genesB->lvlMemS == $genesC->referrerLvl3) {?>
                                <li>
                                    <?php echo $genesC->LevelFullName3?>
                                </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </ul>
                  <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <?php } else { ?>

                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>

        <?php }?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm not so sure if I am heading on the right track I just want a dirty fix that's all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should do it:

```
<?php
$seen = array();
?>
<ul id="org" style="display: none;">
<?php foreach ($lvl1 as $genesA) {?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $genesA->LevelFullName1?>
        <?php if($genesA->lvlMemF) {?>
        <ul>
        <?php if($genesA->lvlMemF) {?>
            <?php foreach ($lvl2 as $genesB) {?>
                <?php if($genesB->lvlMemS) {?>
                <li><?php echo $genesB->LevelFullName2 ?>
                <?php if($genesB->lvlMemS) {?>
                  <ul>
                    <?php if($genesB->lvlMemS) {?>
                        <?php foreach ($lvl3 as $genesC) {?>
                            <?php if($genesB->lvlMemS == $genesC->referrerLvl3) {?>
                                <?php if(!in_array($genesC->LevelFullName3, $seen)?>
                                <li>
                                    <?php echo $genesC->LevelFullName3?>
                                    <?php $seen[] =$genesC->LevelFullName3;?>
                                </li>
                                <?php }?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </ul>
                  <?php } ?>
                </li>
                <?php } else { ?>

                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>

        <?php }?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

you might want to check if my if is at the right place there because it could be that you get empty `ul` blocks if all the names already were seen.

Comment: It still gives me the same output hmmmmm.